# How to simplify $42\sqrt{45} \over 7\sqrt{35}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem is $$42\sqrt{45} \over 7\sqrt{35}$$ HELP! My daughter's math sheet shows how to reduce the squareroots, but the examples all use the same square-root; the problems show two different numbers square-rooted. Can you please help work this problem so I know how to help her with this assignment?

Thanks!

Comment: @MaureenMurphy: I've edited your formula to help us understand it better. Please check and make sure I formatted the formula correctly and that it looks like the one in the homework sheet.  If it doesn't, tell me what is wrong and I will correct it.

Comment: @Dominic: Of course she doesn't mean that. And this person probably hasn't even heard of $\LaTeX$, so be gentle.

Comment: @Mjd i didn't downvote i just want to know what the question is, i can't unterstand the downvotes

Comment: Know the numbers out front are not little they are big, sorry, no idea how to make a sqrt symbol on here, darn technology!

Comment: @Dominic I'm not criticizing your vote, which I don't know anything about; I'm criticizing your comment.

Comment: @MJD you are right I have absolutely no idea what latex means in this realm, in my realm they are gloves that I put on before performing Patient care

Comment: @ MJD thank you that is exactly the equation....now what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{42\sqrt{45}}{7\sqrt{35}} = \frac{6\times 7\sqrt{9\times 5}}{7\sqrt{7\times 5}} $$ 
$$ = \frac{6\sqrt 9 \times \sqrt 5}{\sqrt 7 \times \sqrt 5} = \frac{6\times \sqrt 9}{\sqrt 7}$$
$$= \frac{6 \times 3}{\sqrt 7} \times \frac{\sqrt 7}{\sqrt 7} = \frac{18\sqrt 7}{ 7}$$

Cancel common factors, then multiply denominator to clear the square root.

Comment: You forgot to take the $7$ from the denominator when you divided the $42$ into $6$.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the step by step, she gets it now, still as clear as mud to me!!!! LOL

Comment: I'll stick to Nursing, am definately not a mathmetician

Comment: Just click on the checkmark $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept!

Comment: Thank you all for the help, such a great group!

Comment: You're welcome, and I'm sure we all feel the same way. That's why we're here: we don't get paid, so we're here for the sheer pleasure of helping when we can!

Comment: Kill the fractions Amy. Just do it! ;-) +

Answer (score 5):

Note that $45=5\cdot 9$, hence $\sqrt{45}=3\cdot \sqrt 5$. Also $\sqrt{35}=\sqrt 5\cdot\sqrt 7$. That should help simplify a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Remember that for positive numbers $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\times\sqrt{b}$. So we can simplify as follows:

$$\frac{42\times\sqrt{45}}{7\times\sqrt{35}}=\frac{6\times7\times\sqrt9\times\sqrt5}{7\times\sqrt7\times\sqrt5}=\frac{6\times 3}{\sqrt7}=\frac{18}{\sqrt7}=\frac{18}{\sqrt7}\times1=\frac{18}{\sqrt7}\times\frac{\sqrt7}{\sqrt7}=\frac{18\times\sqrt7}{7}$$

Comment: She says can't end with a radical on the bottom?

Comment: Then $$\frac{18}{\sqrt 7}=\frac{18\sqrt 7}{7}\ldots$$

Comment: History teaches us that radicals always try to get to the top. Mathematics is no exception!

Comment: Please continue we're writing it all down....

Comment: More? There isn't any simpler form. You can maybe insert the $18$ into the radical on top. Or do you mean fake history lessons (which are not fake at all)?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{42 \sqrt{45}}{7 \sqrt{35}} \;\; = \;\; \frac{42}{7} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{45}}{\sqrt{35}} \;\; = \;\; \frac{42}{7} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{45}{35}} \;\; = \;\; \frac{6}{1} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{9}{7}}$$

$$ = \;\; \frac{6}{1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{9}}{\sqrt{7}} \;\; = \;\; \frac{6}{1} \cdot \frac{3}{\sqrt{7}} \;\; = \;\; \frac{6}{1} \cdot \frac{3}{\sqrt{7}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{7}}$$

$$= \;\; \frac{6 \cdot 3 \cdot \sqrt{7}}{1 \cdot \sqrt{7} \cdot \sqrt{7}} \;\; =\;\; \frac{18\sqrt{7}}{7}$$